# After adding libraries to dymola, i can't connect it to Python via buildingspy

Tags: python-3.x, dymola

After i have made some libraries load directly when i open Dymola by modifying the file : "c:/program files (x86)/dymola 2016 fd01/insert/dymola.mos" , and adding those lines :

> Utilities.setenv("MODELICAPATH","C:/Users/hrameh/Desktop/EnergySystems_V2-73p/ModelicaLibraries/ExternalMedia-master/Modelica/ExternalMedia 3.2.1");
>   openModel("C:\Users\hrameh\Desktop\EnergySystems_V2-73p\ModelicaLibraries\ExternalMedia-master\Modelica\ExternalMedia 3.2.1\package.mo");
>   Utilities.setenv("MODELICAPATH","C:\Users\hrameh\Desktop\EnergySystems_V2-73p\ModelicaLibraries\EnergySystems");
>   openModel("C:\Users\hrameh\Desktop\EnergySystems_V2-73p\ModelicaLibraries\EnergySystems\package.mo");
>   Utilities.setenv("MODELICAPATH","\illuin\users$\hrameh\Mes documents\Dymola");

The model works completely fine in Dymola. But, when trying to simulate the model via Python using the buildingspy library, the simulation fails. Any suggestions to help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is, that buildingspy relies on the default working directory path Dymola gets when the dymola.exe is called by buildingspy - but the openModel-commands in your dymola.mos change the working directory.

Use

```
openModel("<path-to-package.mo>", changeDirectory=false);
```

to avoid this.

Additionally, with newer Dymola versions, you must ensure that no saved startup directory is used, by selecting: Edit -> Options -> Settings -> Do not save Startup directory.
As you currently use Dymola 2016 FD01 this is not a problem for you at the moment.

Such problems can be detected by showing the Dymola window when buildingspy simulates a model. You can do this with `showGUI` as shown in this minimum example:

```
import os
from buildingspy.simulate.Simulator import Simulator
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "C:/Program Files (x86)/Dymola 2016 FD01/bin"
s = Simulator("Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller", "dymola")
s.showGUI(show=True)
s.simulate()
```

Some further hints for your example:

- You do not need the Utilities.setenv()-calls to open a library. openModel is sufficient
- I would not use Utilities.setenv, as this is an undocumented and apparently a very old package (creation date is from 2004). Use Modelica.Utilities.System.setEnvironmentVariable instead. This way you also don't get an extra package loaded in the package browser
- Using the file /insert/dymola.mos has some disadvantages:

  - it is used system wide by every user, so it should not contain paths to user directories
  - if you install a new dymola version, you must edit the insert/dymola.mos file of this installation again
- Alternatives to dymola.mos

  - In Dymola 2016 FD01 use the file setup.mos instead to add the openModel commands (located in C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Dynasim)
  - Newer Dymola versions don't have setup.mos anymore, but setup.dymx for the settings and startup.mos for the user commands (to open libraries, etc.)